# sprintf an LPCWSTR variable

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to debug print an `LPCWSTR` string, but I get a problem during the `sprintf` push in the buffer, because it retrieves only the first character from the string.

Here is the code:

```
HANDLE WINAPI hookedCreateFileW(LPCWSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile) {
    char buffer[1024];
    sprintf_s(buffer, 1024, "CreateFileW: %s", lpFileName);
    OutputDebugString(buffer); 
    return trueCreateFileW(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwFlagsAndAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, hTemplateFile);
}
```

For example I get `CreateFileW: C` or `CreateFileW: \`.

How do I properly push it into the buffer?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the wide-char version: `wsprintf_s`?

Answer (score 9):

You need to tell sprintf() that you pass a wide character string.  Use the %ls specifier:

```
 sprintf_s(buffer, 1024, "CreateFileW: %ls", lpFileName);
```

Do note how unproductive this is.  Your code runs on a Unicode operating system.  It must convert your char[] string back to a wide string before it can send it to the debugger.  That's just wasted CPU cycles with a significant risk of data loss to boot.  When you are in Rome, act like a Roman and use wchar_t + wsprintf().  And #define UNICODE so you'll automatically call the fast OutputDebugStringW(), the one that doesn't have to convert the string.  The point of using C++ is to write *fast* code, intentionally making is slow is pointless.

Answer (score 7):

Use [swprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28VS.80%29.aspx) which is the version of sprintf_s which is designed for wide-character strings.

You'll also need an array of `wchar_t` instead of `char` and to use `OutputDebugStringW()`

Also, note you that `swprintf_w` might not be entierly what you want to call. If it encounters a string that is longer than the size you give it, it executes some sort of assertion. I suggest you test this situation specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have a concrete reason to target unicode in this single function (and not, say, in your entire project), it might be wise to use charset-agnostic macros wherever possible:

```
HANDLE WINAPI hookedCreateFile(LPCTSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess, DWORD dwShareMode, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes, DWORD dwCreationDisposition, DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes, HANDLE hTemplateFile) {
 TCHAR buffer[1024];
 _stprintf_s(buffer, 1024, _T("CreateFileW: %s"), lpFileName);
 OutputDebugString(buffer); 
 return trueCreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwFlagsAndAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, hTemplateFile);
}
```